# UK FTSE Sector Indicies Data

Tags: united-kingdom, technical-analysis, historical-data, market-indexes

I am trying to find an on source of FTSE ICB indicies from which I can download historical and current data from. for example I can view the current value of such indices [here](https://shareprices.com/sectors) but I want to also download the historical data but:

- Is it possible to identify these sector indicies by symbol, much like an individual share is e.g. [ACA](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/stocks/summary/company-summary/GB00B61D2N63GBGBXSTMM.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investing.com seems like it might have something useful...

e.g Forestry & Paper at https://uk.investing.com/indices/ftse-350-forestry---paper and there is a tab with historical data too https://uk.investing.com/indices/ftse-350-forestry---paper-historical-data (the "download data" button seemed to need a sign-in... I didn't investigate further).

Similar for mining sector at https://uk.investing.com/indices/mining-historical-data , healthcare and services sector at https://uk.investing.com/indices/ftse-350-health-care-eq.---serv. ... I'm just finding these googling `investing.com FTSE <sector name>`; I assume it has the rest of them.

Those pages have ticker codes on them (e.g mining sector is FTNMX1770 ) which look like they might be useful on other financial info services... for example yahoo finance recognizes NMX1770: https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5ENMX1770/ , and I could download some historical data back to 1986 from the historical data section https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5ENMX1770/history?p=%5ENMX1770 )